# New User with very slow screen draw

Tags: graphics

I have loaded Ubuntu 14.04 and it runs very slowly. I've seen a number of suggestions about using 2D or lightdm but I can't use these:

My login asks for password but doesn't display the logo that would offer a choice of dm

I tried "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm" but the system reported "package 'gdm' is not installed and no information is available".

The symptoms look like those reported as graphics incompatibility (1 character per second in the search text entry, slow and jerky redraw, very jerky youtube, also sections of the screen sometimes look as if they are just displaying interference) but I don't know how to identify the problem. The PC is OK under Windows XP (it's a Dell desktop, pentuium 4, circa 2006) but for how long is anyone's guess.

Is there a way to determine (and hence rectify) the exact problem?

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

Comment: as rajan suggests, you must try using (an ubuntu specific) LXDE(the desktop environment for Lubuntu). It is less resource intensive when compared to unity(which is the default desktop environment in Ubuntu) and so will(must) run without problems in low-end systems.